# How to use ng2-bootstrap datepicker as popup mode?

Tags: typescript, angular, datepicker, ng2-bootstrap

I use ng2-bootstrap date-picker in my project. I want to show the date-picker when I am click on the calendar icon. And also want to hide it when select a date.

```html
<label>Date:</label> 
<div class="datepickerDiv">
   <input type="text" value="{{ getDate() | date:'dd-MMMM-yyyy' }}" class="datepicker"> 
        <span class="cal-icon" (click)="open()"><i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <span class="clearDate" (click)="clearDate()"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <ul class="datepicker-ul" role="menu" *ngIf="opened">
             <datepicker [(ngModel)]="Date" [minDate]="minDate" [showWeeks]="false"></datepicker>
        </ul>
</div>
```

And my component is as follows

```
private opened:boolean = false;
public open():void {
    this.opened = !this.opened;
}

public getDate():number {
    return this.Date && this.Date.getTime() || new Date().getTime();
}

private clearDate() {
    this.Date = null;
}
```

Now the issue was it will be closed only when I click on the icon again.

Answer (score 3):

Just separate "open" and "close" in two functions (now your "open" is actually "toggle"). Then use (not yet documented) event `selectionDone($event)` to close your datepicker.

```
<datepicker [(ngModel)]="dt" [minDate]="minDate" [showWeeks]="false" (selectionDone)="onSelectionDone($event)"></datepicker>
```

and in your code:

```
public onSelectionDone(a) {
    this.close();
}
```